# challenging recursive loop needs to be flatten

Tags: javascript, algorithm

i have recursive array i want to use it inside a loop
here is the code without the loop , i wrote 7 loops individually
i want it in a loop with n number of loops

this is the code on every loop from 0 to 6

```
  var X=[], Y=[], B=[];
  // for example 
  B = [1,1,1,2,7,...];
  var n = B.length
  if(n==0){ X=Y[0]; }
  if(n==1){ X=Y[1][ B[0] ]; }
  if(n==2){ X=Y[2][ B[0] ][ B[1] ]; }
  if(n==3){ X=Y[3][ B[0] ][ B[1] ][ B[2] ]; }
  if(n==4){ X=Y[4][ B[0] ][ B[1] ][ B[2] ][ B[3] ]; }
  if(n==5){ X=Y[5][ B[0] ][ B[1] ][ B[2] ][ B[3] ][ B[4] ]; }
  if(n==6){ X=Y[6][ B[0] ][ B[1] ][ B[2] ][ B[3] ][ B[4] ][ B[5] ]; }
  //... and so on
```

how to make it in a better way to support "i" for high values,
i tried something like this, but it's wrong

```
for(i=0; i<7; i++){
  A = Y[i];
  X = A;
  A = A[B[i]];
}
```

Comment: Show your array structure and your expected output. It's far simpler with recursion or iterative approach.

Comment: This is not 7 loops. This is 1 loop with 7 `if`s

Comment: Is this JS or PHP? Sure looks more like JS than PHP to me.

Comment: um, so X will always be the `X=Y[6][B[0]][B[1]][B[2]][B[3]][B[4]][B[5]];`

Comment: so your array looks like
`[1,[2],[[3]],[[[4]]],[[[[5]]]],[[[[[6]]]]]]` ?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  X = Y[i];
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    X = X[B[j]];
  }
}
```